# Json Schema validate an object exists in the json document (lookup value)

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to do business rule validation using the json-schema spec?

I am trying to use https://json-schema.org/ to validate a json structure in multitple services. One of the rules is an object has to exist in the document somewhere. Essentially it's a lookup value. For example given the following

```
#json document
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Book1",
      "author": 2
    }
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Bo"
    }
  ]
}

#schema
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "books" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "author": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "authors" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the spec is there a way to say "#/books/author" must exist in the `authors` array? Or am I trying to do to much with the spec itself and this should be done with a custom script outside of the schema validator?

As far as I can tell this isn't something that the json-schema spec supports, I just want to verify.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by the JSON Schema standard out of the box. As you mentioned, you would need to do this in your own script/code.